# What so special about events when they are just delegates in C#?

Tags: c#

I am learning about events in C#. I found out that they are just multicast delegates.

My confusion is that why do we have `"event"`  keyword while they are delegate, can't we do

the same as we use delegates.

Comment: +1! I'm learning C# now and I had the same question too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Events are essentialy properties whose types are delegates. The intent of the `event` keyword is to denote what are actually events that an object fires (i.e. callback functions), versus properties that simply hold a delegate. This distinction is important to GUI tools that need to show you what events an object can fire. Of course this could have been done with an annotation, but that wasn't the design that was chosen for C#.

In [a recent interview](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Anders-Hejlsberg-Questions-and-Answers), Anders Hejlsberg (the creator of C#) mentions that if he were designing it over again, he would probably not make events so special.

Answer (score 2):

> the event keyword is a modifier for a
>   delegate declaration that allows it to
>   be included in an interface,
>   constraints it invocation from within
>   the class that declares it, provides
>   it with a pair of customizable
>   accessors (add and remove) and forces
>   the signature of the delegate (when
>   used within the .NET framework).

see [here](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) for a nice explanation.

Comment: Well actually you can add a delegate property in an interface... it's basically the same to me

Comment: as a property yes, but not as a public field.

Answer (score 2):

Events restricts how the list of delegates can be manipulated as you can only add and remove delegates via the `+=` and `-=` operators. Delegates on the other hand do not carry this restriction so given the defintions below.

```
public event DelegateType Events;
public DelegateType Delegates;
```

You can do the following

```
instance.Delegates = null; // clear the list of delegates
```

but the compiler will prevent you from doing

```
instance.Events = null; // doesn't compile
```

When compiled the `Events` field is actually `private` despite its declaration as `public` and the compiler simply adds add/remove methods for manipulating the list.

Answer (score 1):

A member declared with the keyword `event` really is a `MulticastDelegate`. The only specialty about it is that although you declare the event `public` you can only invoke the event / delegate from within your class. This is because the compiler generates a private field storing the delegate and public methods to subscribe to and unsubscribe from the event. If you directly used a `Delegate` anyone from the outside is allowed to invoke the delegate at any time.

So an event is really just a nifty encapsulation of a delegate.